# Left right column divs

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have this HTML and css, I need to make them float next to each other and the right div should auto resized when the left div's with changes and the height of all should open fully on screen, how can I do that please help:

CSS:

```
.ne-divadmincontent
{
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;    

}
.ne-leftcontent
{
    float:left;
}

.ne-rightcontent
{
    float:left;

    border-left:dotted 1px #CCC;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="divadmincontent">

       <div class="ne-leftcontent">
            l-content
      </div>

      <div class="ne-rightcontent"> 
           r-content
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with this but you need to give more info, content and details See http://jsfiddle.net/mRgXS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the width of your two inner div tags *(ne-leftcontent, ne-rightcontent)* they will automatically receive the width of their parent div *(divadmincontent)*

Therefore a solution for your problem would be to assign some value to your inner div tags

```
.ne-leftcontent{
    width:40% // 560px
    float:left;
}

.ne-rightcontent{
    width:60% // 400px
    float:left;
}
```